# Method of use to solve $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10}{n15^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10}{n15^n}$

I encountered this little trouble maker in an exercise, and I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I know I can factor out the $10$, $\displaystyle 10\times\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n15^n}$, but I'm not sure how I simplify $1/n15^n$.

Comment: If you are assigned this problem, then surely you already know the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$, right?

Comment: Is the problem to compute the sum or merely prove that the series converges?

Comment: @BarryCipra To compute the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the generating function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$. Take its derivative $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$, so integrate and compute $f\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the power series $f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}x^n$ which is absoltey convergent for $|x|<1$.

For the derivative of $f$ we have $f'(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Now its your turn to determine $f$ (oberve that $f(0)=0$)

We get  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10}{n15^n}=10 f(\frac{1}{15})$